# Converting clip-path: polygon() to Edge-compatible SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon, clip-path

I'm trying to create a CSS illustration that works across browsers, including Edge.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838485/easiest-way-to-convert-polygon-clip-path-to-microsoft-edge-supported-clippath), I tried to convert the following (working) CSS polygon clip-path to an Edge-compatible, SVG-driven approach. The 1-to-1 method is rendering *something*, but it's not the desired result.

What am I misunderstanding here?

[image]

**Currently working CSS clip-path: polygon()**

```css
.you-headshot {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  background-color: #a3a3a1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.you-headshot div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.you-head-outline {
  background-color: #000;
  clip-path: polygon(48% 6%, 43% 7%, 38% 9%, 34% 12%, 29% 16%, 24% 22%, 22% 30%, 22% 44%, 23% 50%, 23% 65%, 25% 72%, 28% 77%, 32% 82%, 35% 86%, 40% 90%, 43% 92%, 50% 93%, 55% 91%, 62% 87%, 70% 76%, 74% 69%, 75% 64%, 75% 54%, 74% 49%, 74% 40%, 74% 32%, 71% 23%, 66% 15%, 59% 9%, 53% 6%);
}

.you-neck-outline {
  background-color: #000;
  clip-path: polygon(29% 77%, 28% 88%, 23% 100%, 24% 100%, 76% 100%, 68% 90%, 67% 87%, 65% 71%);
}
```

```html
<div class="you-headshot">
  <div class="you-neck-outline">
  </div>
  <div class="you-head-outline">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Not working SVG conversion**

```css
  .you-headshot {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    background-color: #a3a3a1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .you-headshot div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .you-head-outline {
    background-color: #000;
    clip-path: url(#you-head-outline)
  }

  .you-neck-outline {
    background-color: #000;
    clip-path: url(#you-neck-outline)
  }
```

```html
<div class="you-headshot">
 <div class="you-head-outline">
 </div>
 <div class="you-neck-outline">
 </div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <clipPath id="you-head-outline" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points=".48, .6, .43, .7, .38, .9, .34, .12, .29, .16, .24, .22, .22, .30, .22, .44, .23, .50, .23, .65, .25, .72, .28, .77, .32, .82, .35, .86, .40, .90, .43, .92, .50, .93, .55, .91, .62, .87, .70, .76, .74, .69, .75, .64, .75, .54, .74, .49, .74, .40, .74, .32, .71, .23, .66, .15, .59, .9, .53, .6"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="you-neck-outline" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points=".29, .77, .28, .88, .23, .100, .24, .100, .76, .100, .68, .90, .67, .87, .65, .71"/>
  </clipPath>
</svg>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors:

1. The clipPath elements have the same id as the divs. I've changed this by adding `cp-` to the clipping paths id
2. When you transformed from % to units you have 6% = .6 instead of **6% = .06**. Also in your code 100% = .1 instead of **100% = 1**

```css
body{height:500px;}

.you-headshot {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    background-color: #a3a3a1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .you-headshot div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .you-head-outline {
    background-color: #000;
    clip-path: url(#cp-you-head-outline)
  }

  .you-neck-outline {
    background-color: #000;
    clip-path: url(#cp-you-neck-outline)
  }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
 <clipPath id="cp-you-head-outline" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points=".48, .06, .43, .07, .38, .09, .34, .12, .29, .16, .24, .22, .22, .30, .22, .44, .23, .50, .23, .65, .25, .72, .28, .77, .32, .82, .35, .86, .40, .90, .43, .92, .50, .93, .55, .91, .62, .87, .70, .76, .74, .69, .75, .64, .75, .54, .74, .49, .74, .40, .74, .32, .71, .23, .66, .15, .59, .09, .53, .06"/>
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="cp-you-neck-outline" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points=".29, .77, .28, .88, .23, 1, .24, 1, .76, 1, .68, .90, .67, .87, .65, .71"/>
  </clipPath>
 <polygon points=".29, .77, .28, .88, .23, 1, .24, 1, .76, 1, .68, .90, .67, .87, .65, .71"/>
</svg>


<div class="you-headshot">
  <div class="you-neck-outline">
  </div>
  <div class="you-head-outline">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems so obvious! Thank you, can't wait to test this out. Will mark as answer when verified.